# How to pass a Javascript variable into a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and HTML. I have a little problem that I've been trying to fix but don't know how.

I'm trying to pass a variable from a method in a Javascript file into a HTML file, and use its value as if it were HTML code.
I know that the Javascript file is passed correctly into the HTML, the problem is just getting the variable from it.

Here is the relevant Javascript method:

```
function getCode()  {
    var myCode ="Hello World";
    document.getElementById("myCode").innerHTML = "<a>" + myCode + "</a>";
}
```

And here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<body>
    <a href="myCode" onclick="getCode()">
    <code id="myCode" class="prettyprint"> myCode </code>
</body>
```

I don't know if I am doing it correct. I simply need the variable myCode to be turned into just HTML code, in other words myCode in the HTML should be turned to "Hello World" at this point:

```
<code class="prettyprint"> myCode </code>
```

Comment: Should work just fine, but using code tags means the HTML is formatted, and setting a href value means the anchor redirects when clicking it.

Comment: Also, don't forget to close the `<a>` tag. Example: `<a ...><code id...></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/bGQy5/

```
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="getCode()">Click me</a>

    <br/><br/>

    <code id="myCode" class="prettyprint"> Text
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </code>


</body>

window.getCode = function () {
   var myCode = "Hello World";
   document.getElementById("myCode").innerHTML = "<a>" + myCode + "</a>";
 }
```

Please note a few issues though:

- you are not closing your first  tag, this is not good
- you should be setting a "HREF" tag on your link to make it clickable.
- you need to have the reference to a function (e.g. by attaching it to window or similar)
- you'd be better off using a javascript library, like jquery

Comment: Ok, sorry, the copy/paste below does. I was looking at the wrong snipplet.

Answer (score 2):

When clicking the link, the browser will change the address bar to `myCode`, because that's what the anchor's `href` attribute points to.

I'm guessing this is not what you wanted, so you can change the value of the `href` attribute to something like `#` to prevent this from happening.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getCode()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work just fine, but setting a href value means the anchor redirects when clicking it.

```
<a id="myCode" href="#" onclick="getCode()">click</a>
<code id="myCode" class="prettyprint"> myCode </code>

<script>
    function getCode()  {
        var myCode ="Hello World";
        document.getElementById("myCode").innerHTML = "<a>" + myCode + "</a>"; 
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7SHnX/)